# Trigger a link to fire with form selection in If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form > and a switch button within that form.

The switch button field looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="promotionFacebook" <%if (offer.get('promotionFacebook')) {%>checked<%}%>  enabled>
```

The form sends with an 'Activate' button >

And that function looks like:

```
activateBtnClick:function () {
   this.saveBtnClick(null,{active: true});
```

I am seeking to add an if / else statement as a solution to 'Activate' the form; and based on if the switch button is set to 'on' -- a link triggers. In this case; a link to 'Send to Facebook'.

Below is how I am starting the solution:

```
    activateBtnClick:function () {
        this.saveBtnClick(null,{active: true});
        if (condition)
           statement1
        [else
           statement2]
    },
```

I would like to trigger this link; if condition facebook is checked.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images[0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT
```

So essentially; you toggle 'Facebook Enabled' and submit (or in my case 'Activate') the form; the JavaScript loads the link to trigger with the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `$('#promotionFacebook').is(':checked')`

Comment: Yes that is the general idea.

Comment: +1 - for the answer. but keep you answers away from question formatting :)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I was not entirely sure if that was what he was looking for, hence the question format! You are right though.